# Throwing an Exception in the object constructor

Tags: java, exception, constructor

Lets say I've this code:

```
public class MyClass {

    public final static int valueA = 0;
    public final static int valueB = 1;

    private int parameter = -1;

    public MyClass(int parameter) {

        if(parameter != valueA && parameter != valueB) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exception description here");
        }

        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

}
```

Is this a best practice? Or is there a better way to grantee that whatever the value passed on the constructor it has the same value as one of those variables?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with checking parameters and throwing an IAE in the constructor. If we're talking about best practices, there is something that should be noted here: when the parameter to the constructor is mutable, always make a defensive copy first and check the constraints on the copy. (And then of course use the copy.)

Comment: fail early, they say

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java API contains many classes that throw exceptions in their constructors, so there's nothing wrong with that.

Example :

In `java.net.URI` class :

```
public URI(String str) throws URISyntaxException {
    new Parser(str).parse(false);
}
```

In `java.util.ArrayList` class :

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity) {
    super();
    if (initialCapacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal Capacity: "+
                                           initialCapacity);
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
}
```

Comment: Accepted your answer because it answers my main question and straight to the point. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should look into `Enum`s.

```
public enum MyEnum {

    A(0),
    B(1);

    private int parameter;

    public MyEnum(int parameter)
    {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }

}
```

Basically, this forces that you can only have the object with the `parameter = 0`,or `parameter = 1`. However, this also only allows ONE instance of each type (0, 1, etc...), so this may not work depending on your use case.